# React - how to pass css modules className to a custom component

Tags: css, reactjs, react-typescript, css-modules, react-css-modules

Is it possible to pass an isolated className to a custom component using CSS Modules, so I can use it inside this component?

```
<CustomComponent className={style.foo}/>
```

Comment: What does not work? Provided that you apply the `className` in your component template, it should work. If not, please make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: What is the expected behaviour? Provided you setup everything correctly this should work. How does your import statement look (the one you are getting `style` variable from)? How does the CSS file you are importing look? What is your loader and what configuration does it have? Please provide additional details.